# Swift mail is not catching exception for an invalid email

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm using Swift mailer to send emails, it's not catching exception on invalid email address & throws an error.

My code is:

```
try
{
    $message->setBody($html, "text/html");
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
}
catch(Swift_RfcComplianceException $e)
{
    echo "Address ".$email." seems invalid";
}
```

For an email address which doesn't comply with RFC it just throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception Swift_RfcComplianceException with message Address
in mailbox given [ex@example@ex.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
thrown in /swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php on line 352
```

Can anybody help resolving it? Simply it should catch an exception so other functions are not affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrapping the `try ... catch`-block around the wrong part of your composition of the swiftmailer mail.

Excerpt from [the manual](http://swiftmailer.org/pdf/Swiftmailer.pdf):

> If you add recipients automatically based on a data source that may
>   contain invalid email addresses, you can prevent possible exceptions
>   by validating the addresses using `Swift_Validate::email($email)` and
>   only adding addresses that validate. Another way would be to wrap your
>   `setTo()`, `setCc()` and `setBcc()` calls in a try-catch block and handle
>   the `Swift_RfcComplianceException` in the catch block.

Therefore you should use it while adding addresses to your `Swift_Message`-object, like this:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

// add some message composing here...

$email = "somewrongadress.org";
try {
    $message->setTo(array($email));
} catch(Swift_RfcComplianceException $e) {
    echo "Address ".$email." seems invalid";
}
```

Additionally, I'd advise some try-catch around the `$result = $mailer->send($message);` too, since it might throw an exception if something else is wrong.